# When setting an Adapter it Gives a Null Pointer Exception in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am a new android learner. I ran into this null pointer exception at `setAdapter()` for lListView`. Both the`ListView` and the Adapter are NOT null.
I have attached my logcat and fragament, adapter code. I have searched the Internet, and I thought it might have something to do with Fragment.

**News_Title_fragment:**

```
package com.example.fragmentbestpractice;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NewsTitleFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView newsTitleListView;

    private List<News> newsList;

    private NewsAdapter adapter;

    private boolean isTwoPane;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        newsList = getNews();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(activity, R.layout.news_item, newsList);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_title_frag, container, false);
        newsTitleListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title_list_view);
        newsTitleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        newsTitleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.news_content_layout) != null) {
            isTwoPane = true;
        } else {
            isTwoPane = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        News news = newsList.get(position);
        if (isTwoPane) {
            NewsContentFragment newsContentFragment = (NewsContentFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.news_content_fragment);
            newsContentFragment.refresh(news.getTitle(), news.getContent());
        } else {
            NewsContentActivity.actionStart(getActivity(), news.getTitle(),
                    news.getContent());
        }
    }

    private List<News> getNews() {
        List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();
        News news1 = new News();
        news1.setTitle("Succeed in College as a Learning Disabled Student");
        news1.setContent("College freshmen will soon learn to live with a roommate, adjust to a new social scene and survive less-than-stellar dining hall food. Students with learning disabilities will face these transitions while also grappling with a few more hurdles.");
        newsList.add(news1);
        News news2 = new News();
        news2.setTitle("Google Android exec poached by China's Xiaomi");
        news2.setContent("China's Xiaomi has poached a key Google executive involved in the tech giant's Android phones, in a move seen as a coup for the rapidly growing Chinese smartphone maker.");
        newsList.add(news2);
        return newsList;
    }

}
```

NewsAdapter:

```
package com.example.fragmentbestpractice;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

    private int resourceId;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<News> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        News news = getItem(position);
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        TextView newsTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        newsTitleText.setText(news.getTitle());
        return view;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
 06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.youdianin.fragamentbestpratice/com.youdianin.fragamentbestpratice.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:417)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:334)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.youdianin.fragamentbestpratice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5086)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    ... 11 more
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at com.youdianin.fragamentbestpratice.NewsTitleFragment.onCreateView(NewsTitleFragment.java:51)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4742)
06-30 21:45:03.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31769):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
```

Comment: Where is NullPointerEexception in your logcat trace?

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: The problem is in your xml layout for MainActivity, posting that might get you help

Comment: There is no `NullPointerException` here. Also, there must be more of the stacktrace. Your problem is occuring while inflating the XML layout for your Fragment.

Comment: I have  updated my logcat, pls help me out of this~